# Java Hex Number and Conditionals

Tags: java, types, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java so I have a problem with hex numbers usage in conditionals and its sizes. There is some issue about Scanner class too. I have searched java documents for primitive data types.

The program is about; take a number and look in which data type it could be written and print the appropriate data type.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Integer;


public class Solution{
   public static void main(String []argh)
    {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      long t=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {

        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=0x81 || x<=0x7f)System.out.println("* byte");
            if(x<=0x7fff || x>=0x8001)System.out.println("* short");
            if(x<=0x7fffffff || x>=0x80000001)System.out.println("* int");

            //if(x<= (0x7fffffffffffffff)|| x>= 
                       //(0x8000000000000001))System.out.println("*long");
            System.out.printf("\n\n%x\n\n",x);
            System.out.println();
        }
            catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

      }
   }
 }
```

Questions:

1. I get an error message for commented "if()" conditional "too large int :0x7fffffffffffffff " why is that so?
2. I run the program by commenting some "if()" and give it "10" to search possible data types but this time it prints just only "int" datatype.
3. If I give it "0x7b" as input it carries out to "catch()" section. Why?

Could you please explain it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get an error message for commented "if()" conditional "too large int :0x7fffffffffffffff " why is that so?

Because `0x7fffffffffffffff` is an `int` literal. `7fffffffffffffff` can't fit into an int. It can fit into a `long` though. To make it a `long` literal, you have to add `l` or `L` at the end:

```
if(x<= (0x7fffffffffffffffL)|| x>=
    (0x8000000000000001L))System.out.println("*long");
```

But this `if` statement is redundant, because `x` is already of type `long`, so by definition, its value must fit in `long`.

Actually, using the `MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE` constants of each type is less error-prone to write than numeric literals:

```
System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
if(x>=Byte.MIN_VALUE || x<=Byte.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* byte");
if(x>=Short.MIN_VALUE || x<=Short.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* short");
if(x>= Integer.MIN_VALUE || x<=Integer.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* int");
System.out.println("*long");
```

> I run the program by commenting some "if()" and give it "10" to search possible data types but this time it prints just only "int" datatype.

I cannot reproduce this. Which if statements did you comment out?

> If I give it "0x7b" as input it carries out to "catch()" section. Why?

`Scanner.nextLong` does not recognise hex numbers, unfortunately. You can read the number as a string, check its prefix, if it's `0x`, then strip off the first two characters, and parse it as a hex number.

Comment: Thank you I didn't expect to write "l" for "long". Is it possible that in java hex numbers not work as expected like C++ because I changed all hex values by its class defined final numbers like; Interger.MAX_VALUE and all stuff worked fine as expected. A little bit confusing... My background is C++ so I am getting used to it. Thanks.

Comment: Use L for long literals. l looks far too much like a 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner True. With the font I am using (Monaco), they are quite different. Edited anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1) this number does not fit into an integer, use a long literal: 0x7fffffffffffffffL

2) unclear, which if did you comment out?

3) this format is not understood by the Scanner, use decimal representation

But, you should also reconsider your conditions. They don't work the way you intended. For example 300 would be classified as byte. (because 300 > 129).